# Cookie based Redirection using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I'm attempting to create a redirect based on a cookie existence. So when a user connects to my website `jonathanstevens.org` for the first time, they are redirected to `jonathanstevens.org/landing`

Code parts:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Global.js

```js
function create_cookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime( date.getTime() + (days*24*60*60*1000) );
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}

function get_cookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) {
            return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Index.html

```html
<!-- redirect to landing page -->
<script>
  // Redirect to landing page if 'form_submitted' cookie does not exist
  if (get_cookie('secondvisit') === 'undefined') {
    window.location.href = "landing.html";
  }
</script>
```

landing.html

```html
<!-- Adds second Visit cookie -->
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Create cookie so that the user is no longer redirected
    create_cookie('secondvisit', 'true', 30);
 });
</script>
```

The expected result was it to check for a cookie, then forward me to my landing page if it wasn't defined. Any ideas on what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should compare with `null` instead of `undefined` as you are returning `null` from the function `get_cookie`

Index.html

```
<!-- redirect to landing page -->
<script>
  // Redirect to landing page if 'form_submitted' cookie does not exist
  if (get_cookie('secondvisit') === null) {
    window.location.href = "landing.html";
  }
</script>
```

Apart from this you should use this [library](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) really good one an easy to work with see below

**Create a cookie, valid across the entire site:**

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value');
```

**Create a cookie that expires 7 days from now, valid across the entire site:**

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: 7 });
```

**Create an expiring cookie, valid to the path of the current page:**

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value', { expires: 7, path: '' });
```

**Read cookie:**

```
Cookies.get('name'); // => 'value'
Cookies.get('nothing'); // => undefined
```

**Read all visible cookies:**

```
Cookies.get(); // => { name: 'value' }
```

**Delete cookie:**

```
Cookies.remove('name');
```

**Delete a cookie valid to the path of the current page:**

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value', { path: '' });
Cookies.remove('name'); // fail!
Cookies.remove('name', { path: '' }); // removed!
```

---

**EDIT**

A converted version of your code using `js.cookie` library will look like following.

*(Note: i have tested this code and it works correctly, make sure you are including the library correctly and there are no errors on the console.)*

**Index.html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<!-- redirect to landing page -->
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (typeof Cookies.get('secondvisit') === 'undefined') {
            window.location.href = "landing.html";
        }
    })
    // Redirect to landing page if 'form_submitted' cookie does not exist
</script>
```

**landing.html**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@2/src/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<!-- Adds second Visit cookie -->
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        // Create cookie so that the user is no longer redirected
        var a = Cookies.set('secondvisit', 'true', {
            expires: 7
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. This has got the redirection working. However when page "landing" loads, it does not create a cookie. So when I click back onto index.html it redirects me again. (I am working local on chrome). 
`<script> jQuery(document).ready(function($) { cookies.set('secondvisit', 'true'); }); </script>`
I have also included the library you suggested.

Comment: i am out at the moment will reach back home and see what i can do to sort it out.

Comment: apart from all it is `Cookies.set()` not `cookies.set()` so that may be the reason it wasnt working for you, i have added the code above. @JonathanStevens

Comment: Does this work on my local file system or will I have to upload it. If so, maybe that's the issue...

Comment: Excellent information I have looking for, thank you.

Comment: glad i could help @Woody