# how to redirect webpage based on user preference?

Tags: url, cookies, redirect

I'm looking to implement a functionality from [NewEgg](https://www.newegg.com) website. Once you visit `newegg.com`, it does a location detection and a popup will ask you whether you want to be redirected to your country-specific subdomain/website. Once you allow the website gets redirected. For eg. If you are in Hong Kong, the site gets redirected to `https://www.newegg.com/global/hk/`
Next time you open the browser and type `newegg.com` it automatically gets redirected to Hong Kong website.

How do they do that? How to implement this type of functionality?
I'm assuming they store a cookie, but how to do the redirection using that cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this by setting an cookie. Let save a cookie named **locationlogged** which contain user details, IP, location and anything else you want to store. Also preform this cookie check on **newegg.com** always. So when any user visit **newegg.com** you should call Cookie Cheker function to check wheather user previously selected any location or not. If set then get location value from cookie and redirect to new domain.

Make sure always call cookie checker function after loading dependency, libraries, html files. Otherwise sometime it may produce bad redirection warnings.

It would be good if you can show a popup on **newegg.com** saying "Hey ! we found your previous selected location. Is it right ?" and show buttons like redirect to selected or change location etc.

More you can also see how to do this in Jquery here : [Cookie based Redirection using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47686107/cookie-based-redirection-using-javascript)